# Android Timer: How to set callback object in TimerTask()

Tags: android, zxing

What I want to do is read QR code by using ZXing. I made it via touch event, but I want to read QR codes without tap gesture.

I guess I can do it by using Timer but I do not know how to set call back listeners.

Does anybody know the solutions? Thanks

onTouchEvent. It works.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mCamera.autoFocus(this);
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Timer. It does not work.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mCamera != null) {
                        mCamera.autoFocus(this); // "this" is not available..
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 2000);
}
```

[UPDATE SOLVED]

Tnanks to @user2713030, I fixed it. And I noticed that autofocus() should be in surfaceCreated().

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (mCamera != null) {
                                mCamera.autoFocus(MainActivity.this);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 2000);
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `mCamera.autoFocus(MyActivity.this)`. Or `getActivity()` if you're within a `Fragment`.

Comment: You are the greatest!